# Diameter increase approximation (Linearization)

Tags: linearization

**The diameter of a tree was 10 in. During the following year, the
circumference increased 2 in. About how much did the tree’s
diameter increase? The tree’s cross-section area?**

we are using linearization to predict the increase as you can see in the question but I couldn't figure out what to do

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula $$A=\pi R^2$$ and $$C=2\pi R = \pi D$$ to get

$$dC=\pi dD$$ and $$dA=2\pi R dR$$

You know the values of $dC$ and $R$ so you can find $dD$ and $dA$